# Doing multiple arithmetics in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get the percentage of a value and adding it up with itself again using vuejs.
This is a sample:
5 / 100 * 900 + 900 = 945.00 ( normal way )

5 / 100 * 900 + 900 = 90045 ( Vuejs way)

This is my code below:

```
<td>
  <input name="amount[]" v-model="row.amount" style="width: 94px;" type="text">
</td>
<td>
  <select name="vat[]" v-model="row.vat" style="width: 94px;" class="form-control">
    <option value="0" selected>0%</option>
    <option value="5">5 %</option>
  </select>

</td>
<td>
  <input type="hidden" :value="row.vat / 100 * row.amount" v-model="gross_am">
  <input value="" name="gross[]" :value="row.amount + gross_am" v-model="row.gross | currencyDisplay" style="width: 94px;"
    type="text">
</td>
```

The point is I'm trying to get the gross amount of the amount entered, to get the gross amount the user will enter the amount and select the vat value from the drop down and the arithmetic triggers. which is the percentage of the value plus the value = gross amount 
Thanks.
(Im still a vuejs noob)

Comment: You really should be using computed properties rather than inlining things like this in your code `row.vat / 100 * row.amount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `row.amount` and `gross_am` are strings. The `+` operator is used for both string concatenation and for arithmetical operations. If both values are strings, they are concatenated. In your case the strings "900" and "45" get concatenated to "90045". To avoid this, convert the values to Integers manually.

```
<input value="" name="gross[]"  :value="parseInt(row.amount) + parseInt(gross_am)" v-model="row.gross | currencyDisplay"  style="width: 94px;"
                                       type="text">
```